# i want to get the user unique id. how do i fetch it using getKey method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();

//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);
                String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In the line of string list_user_id = getRef(Position).getKey(): I guess this is returning null because when the user clicks on the item in listview

```
 usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            intent.putExtra("visit_user_id",list_user_id);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

He will be directed to chat activity... as soon as i open chat avtivity im getting null pointerexception on this line

```
   MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getExtras().get("visit_user_id").toString();
```

Where have i gone wrong? trying to make a chat application so need to fetch the unique id of the user...
Database screenshot http://ibb.co/cwOQtx

getting a null error again

```
rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(messages);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

error in the line rootref.chil("messages")........
Error- http://ibb.co/h4D2dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code( inside of ValueEventListener) :

```
String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
```

to this:

```
String list_user_id = ds.getKey();
```

`for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` *ds* here is iterating inside the direct children which are the unique ids, then by using the above you will be able to retrieve the unique ids.

Also according to the firebase docs:

getRef() does not accept any parameters.

more info here:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getRef()

Comment: @PeterHadded: most likely that snippet was copied from code using FirebaseUI. The adapter's in that library have a `getRef()` method that takes the position of the item to get the reference for.

Comment: @CourtneyMiller where are u getting null? on this line `MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getExtras().get("visit_user_id").toString();`? Try this then         `String recieved=getIntent().getStringExtra("visit_user_id");`. The above answer should be correct and it should give you the ids that you want. You need to add breakpoints on the null line to see why it is null. But the above will retrieve for sure. Then u use putExtra to send the data to the next activity. And in the next activity you get null, try this in the answer and comment and add a breakpoint to check more if it did not work

Comment: again a null error... can u look to the edited question and help me out please????

Comment: @CourtneyMiller the edit is completely different than the original??? Inside the `onChildAdded` initialize the adapter and set the adapter. Example this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);` and this `list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @CourtneyMiller remove `child(MessageRecieverId)` also `Akash` and `Savitha` are not ids.. delete those

Comment: i have done it in the oncreate method... its recycler view.................

    userMessageList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messageList);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        userMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        userMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        userMessageList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164572/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-courtney-miller).